# How to get values from many to many relationships in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following two models.

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rules', null=True, blank=True)
    threshold = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    alert_value = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    is_internal = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'threshold': self.threshold,
            'alert_value': self.alert_value
        }


class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_internal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rules = models.ManyToManyField(Rule)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'description': self.description,
            'rules': [r.to_json() for r in self.rules.all()]
        }

   def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

Now I have a method to save the module in my views.py.

```
def create_module(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        module_name = request.POST.get('name')
        module_description = request.POST.get('description')
        rule_ids = request.POST.getlist('rule_id')
        module = models.Module(name=module_name,
                           description=module_description)
        module.save()
        rules =  models.Rule.objects.filter(pk__in=rule_ids)
        module.rules = rules
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

and a method to retrieve the module

```
def get_module(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        module_ids = request.GET.getlist('module_id')
        modules = models.Module.objects.filter(pk__in=module_ids)
        response = [module.to_json() for module in modules if module.name is not 
                None]
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), 
                                   content_type='application/json')
```

However when I try to retrieve I get an empty rules list . I print the rules object while saving it gets printed so I indeed save it. But printing using `get_module` return

`[{"rules": [], "name": "module_name", "description": "first description"}]`

I am struggling as to why my rules list is empty there.

Comment: Stupid question -- but are you sure there are rules in your database? If you can check manually, and make sure that `rule_ids` has a valid range, that would be good information to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think `rules` is saved:

try this way in your `create_module()` function:

```
#...
rules =  models.Rule.objects.filter(pk__in=rule_ids)
for rule in rules: 
    module.rules.add(rule)
# instead of: module.rules = rules
```

Comment: your rules arenot being saved obviously. i edited my answer. try to add the m2m relation this way